# App.Config GetSection not returning subsection values

Tags: c#, .net, app-config, vs-unit-testing-framework

I have an app.config with following Section,

```
   <configSections>
     <section name="Identity" 
   type="MyProject.Test.Configuration.IdentitySection, MyProject" />
    </configSections>

    <Identity>
       <Services>
         <IdentityToken endpoint="example.com/api/token" timeout="60"/>
         <Service endpoint="localhost/EmployeeService.svc" />
       </Services>
       <Proxy proxyurl="example2.com" proxyuser="user1readonly" 
          proxypassword="xxxxx" clientId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 
            clientSecret="xxxx"/>
      </Identity>
```

Then after ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Identity") as below,

```
    IdentityConfigModel identitySection = 
      ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Identity") as IdentityConfigModel ;
```

getting the following object values,

**identitySection.Services.IdentityToken.Endpoint** &
**identitySection.Services.Service.Endpoint** as **null**

I can see the Keys in the returned object but the respective values are showing null. There is no case sensitive issues since I can see the names in the object, but values are null

Am I doing anything wrong in Appconfig? or Am I  doing the GetSection part wrongly?